# Qual è il senso di "provare" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Al mio ritorno, dopo i due anni trascorsi in sanatorio, tu eri disoccupato. Ti avevano licenziato da un ufficio per «scarso rendimento». L’esperienza dei quotidiani rapporti col mondo ostile, e delle quotidiane rinunzie a cui è costretta la povera gente, **ti aveva già provato**. Era evidente che avevi subìto un trauma dal quale soltanto adesso ti riprendevi.

Potreste spiegarmi il senso del costrutto "ti aveva già provato" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "provare" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tante accezioni che appaiono, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'espressione che si trova nel testo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo contesto il significato di ***provato*** è indebolito, logorato.

Su Treccani per [provare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/provare/) trovi la seguente accezione:

> 4. a. Cimentare, mettere alla prova: *le avversità provano l’uomo; **la terribile esperienza l’ha molto provata**;* con partic. riferimento
>      all’integrità fisica e psichica di una persona, indebolire, logorare:
>      *il lungo digiuno (o il periodo di prigionia) lo ha duramente provato;
>      il lavoro in miniera prova anche i fisici più robusti*.

e sul Treccani sinonimi e contrari per [provare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/provare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> 4. [sottoporre a prove per superare le quali occorre resistenza, coraggio e sim.: *le avversità provano l'uomo; **il lungo digiuno lo ha
>      duramente provato***]  ≈ (lett., non com.) cimentare, mettere alla (o a
>      dura) prova. ↑ indebolire, logorare.

Comment: Giusto, ma io farei riferimento al vocabolario vero e proprio, anziché a quello dei sinonimi e contrari, cioè al punto 4 di [_provare_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/provare/).

Comment: Ho recepito la tua osservazione e ho mantenuto anche quella iniziale proveniente dal sinonimi e contrari